# Solving 4D coupled system by using EULER'S Method

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, ode

I want to implement the system given below in code, but when I increase it to 1500 iterations, then I get the following errors:

> ```
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "D:\python test files\sys1.py", line 16
>     dy = c*x- x*z + w
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "D:\python test files\sys1.py", line 17
>     dz = -b*z + x*y
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "D:\python test files\sys1.py", line 18
>     du = -h*u - x*z
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "D:\python test files\sys1.py", line 42
>     zs[i+1] = zs[i] + (dz * t)
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "D:\python test files\sys1.py", line 15
>     dx = a*(y-x) + u
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "D:\python test files\sys1.py", line 19
>     dw = k1*x - k2*y
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\proj3d.py", line 156
>     txs, tys, tzs = vecw[0]/w, vecw[1]/w, vecw[2]/w   
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
> ```

**My code:**

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np    
import math    
import random   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D        
# import pdb
# pdb.set_trace()

def sys1(x, y, z, u, w , a=10, b=8.0/3.0, c=28, k1=0.4, k2=8, h=-2):

    dx = a*(y-x) + u
    dy = c*x- x*z + w    
    dz = -b*z + x*y    
    du = -h*u - x*z    
    dw = k1*x - k2*y    
    return dx, dy, dz, du, dw

t = 0.01    
itera = 2500

# Need one more for the initial values

xs = np.empty((itera+1,))    
ys = np.empty((itera+1,))    
zs = np.empty((itera+1,))    
us = np.empty((itera+1,))    
ws = np.empty((itera+1,))

# Setting initial values

xs[0], ys[0], zs[0], us[0], ws[0] = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)


# Stepping through "time".

for i in range(itera):    
# Derivatives of the X, Y, Z state
    dx, dy, dz, du, dw = sys1(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i], us[i], ws[i])     

    xs[i+1] = xs[i] + (dx * t)
    ys[i+1] = ys[i] + (dy * t)
    zs[i+1] = zs[i] + (dz * t)
    us[i+1] = us[i] + (du * t)
    ws[i+1] = ws[i] + (dw * t)

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(xs, ys, zs)
ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
ax.set_zlabel("Z Axis")
ax.set_title("Lorenz Attractor")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Somewhere you are dividing by zero which is giving the warnings.

Comment: Although when I run the code I don't get any of the warnings you get.. What version of python/matplotlib are you using?

Comment: i am using python 2.7.6 and matplotlib 1.3.1.

Comment: I have looked through your code and when `itera` reaches the value 1590, `dy` and `du` equal infinity and `dz` equals minus infinity. And above this, all your values, `dx,dy,dz,du,dw` are all infinity. This is where your problem is.

Comment: thanks david, but i need the system to iterate for more values,in MATLAB i did it but in python here it shows problem,you have any suggestions to implement this using any other way?

Comment: Your system seems 5D to me... not that it matters much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to simulate a famously sensitive system of nonlinear differential equations (actually, a *buffed up* version of [a famously sensitive system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system#Overview)) with a famously simple numerical scheme. Your solution diverges at a given time step, which manifests itself in your solution values first becoming `inf` (which you don't notice), then `nan` (which you still don't notice), then finally the scaling in `Axes3D.plot` produces a division by zero while juggling around your infinities.

Here's your output as-is:

[image: before]

Notice the axes limit scales: all are above 1e100. This could've told you that you have infinities running around.

The good news is that the very same program you have can give reasonable output just by decreasing the time step, which should always be your first guess with a first-order method like Euler's (especially that you're convinced from a MATLAB implementation that your algorithm is correct).

Example outputs using `t=0.001; itera=25000` (left) and `t=0.0001; itera=250000` (right):

[image: smaller dt] [image: even smaller dt]

Firstly, note that the two plots are fairly reasonable, and blatantly finite. Secondly, note that the two trajectories, while having a generally similar shape, are very different. If you would use longer iterations (by which I mean longer total `t*itera`), the differences would become gradually more pronouned, and eventually the two trajectories would part ways completely.

You should make sure you understand that you are using a very inaccurate method to plot the trajectory of a very sensitive (to be precise: chaotic) system. Even with a very accurate method you'll eventually accumulate some errors, and you'll deviate from the actual solution to your initial-value problem. All you can hope for is to plot out the rough shape of the attractor, around which the trajectories will inevitably be zigzagging. But I'm fairly certain that's your goal to begin with.

Comment: thanks alot sir...i did that mistake and understood and get really pretty output as i desired.now if i want to implement the same system by using 4rth order Runge kutta method,can you assist me here?
thanks again for such a detail answer.wish you best wishes sir.

Comment: @faiz that is a completely different problem, and you will have to implement that yourself. If you run into problems along the way and you can't solve them by yourself, feel free to ask a new question about your new problem. If you believe this answer of mine answers the question you asked here, please consider marking my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: i check add sir,actually i had ask the same question but i didn't got any satisfied answer because in the literature i know the implentation of Runge kutta method for one or two equation but i don't know for more than 3 coupled equation,therefore i asked,thanks sir.

Comment: @faiz thank you. I don't understand why you're saying "I didn't get any satisfactory answer", since there's an answer there to which you replied in February that "thanks a lot sir". And anyway, as the users there said it: if you know how to implement it for 1d, you should easily do it for 5d: use vectors instead of scalars at each time point, and each coordinate is described by its own equation. It should be quite straightforward. So what exactly is your problem there?

Comment: aahhh sorry sir and thanks for your assistant,actually i feel a little embarrassed to ask question again,but in this code:
    for i=2:N+1
        k1 = odefunc(time        , state           );
        k2 = odefunc(time + 0.5*h, state + 0.5*h*k1);
        k3 = odefunc(time + 0.5*h, state + 0.5*h*k2);
        k4 = odefunc(time +     h, state +     h*k3);
        state = state + (h/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);
        time = time + h
i can't run this,
i am confused about the values of K1,K2,K3,K4 for more than 2d system.how to make changes?

Comment: and now the main thing is that i wana implement that system in Python,the above method is Eulers METHOD,the performance of euler's is not so perfect as RK4,

Comment: @faiz If you're more familiar with MATLAB, then first implement RK4 with that, and then translate to python. First try to implement RK4 for a 1d problem. If you can do that, you just have to do the same thing for a vector-valued function: the functions and its derivatives are vectors rather than arrays for each `t` point, otherwise the machinery is the same. And what exactly do you mean that you "can't run" the other answer. Are you familiar with MATLAB enough to translate that SCILAB solution to MATLAB?

Comment: thank you sir,and sorry i am alittle dumb,honestly speaking i am not familiar with that.

Comment: @faiz You can't really avoid learning well one of the languages involved. Either MATLAB, or python (with numpy). There are a lot of tutorials where RK4 and other numerical methods are explained, you should look around, learn, then try to implement it. If an implementation of yours doesn't work, we can help you debug; but we can't write your code for you.

Comment: thanks for suggestions sir.i really respect you,i will follow your suggestions,be happy sir

Comment: I know what most of the equations and values are, but what are du and dw? Like, where do they come from? What are the values h, k1, and k2? Thank you!

Comment: @MatthewSpire the first three equations are what defines the famous Lorenz system. OP has a generalized set of differential equations with two more variables. I don't know what it describes and what the parameters are, I just helped them fix their code. You have to ask OP what their model describes.